# If you are multi-targeting an assembly how should you name the files?

Tags: .net, silverlight, assemblies

If you are multi-targeting an assembly how should you name the files?

For example if you are targeting both standard .net and silverlight should the files be named differently?

Something like MyProject.dll and MyProject.Silverlight.dll

Or should they be named the same but exist in different directories

Something like DotNet\MyProject.dll and Silverlight\MyProject.dll

Thanks

Edit: Both RhinoMocks and Prism use the ".Silverlight" approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our current project we append .Silvelight to the the assembly and project name while keeping the namespace the same as the .Net assembly.

We dont have any of the problems that the above to comments mention as we aren't sharing any XAML and we use TFS, CI and dependency replication for our builds.

One of the benefits is that you can visualy identify the silverlight assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to make them have identical names. After all, it's essentially the same assembly, content-wise. This way, it's easier to mix and match stuff just by replacing the assembly file and not changing build scripts.

Comment: Yes. When you have the assemblies named the same, it makes things like re-using xaml files a lot easier (since you don't have to change the xmlns declarations).